# Application hangs when debugging on iOS 3.1.3 device with Xcode 4.3.2

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, itunes, ipod-touch

I have the original iPod touch with iOS 3.1.3 (the last one that can run on the device). When I use Xcode 4.3.2 to debug an application, it always hangs at the launch image screen. However the application runs fine when I disconnect the device and run it without Xcode.

Is there a way to fix this? I've reinstalled iTunes 10.6 and restarted both my Mac and the iPod, with no effect.

This is Xcode's screen when I pressed "pause" on the debugger. Maybe this can be somewhat useful for identifying the issue.

[image: Xcode debugging paused]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For what it's worth, I see this behavior also on an iOS 3.2 iPad. I have been assuming it's a bug in the debugger support for 3.x devices, but have no official word.

Comment: I am also having same issue with Xcode 4.3.2 and debugging on iOS 3.1.3 on iPhone 3G.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem, I fixed it by editing the project scheme to use the GDB Debugger instead of the LLDB Debugger when running the app.

Comment: check, that fixed issues for me too (whole of Xcode hangs when using LLDB).